# Require help in validating the IpAddress string using Regex

Tags: regex

I have string in format:

172.60.136.145,172.60.136.146,172.60.136.147,........

and I need help in validating the IpAddresses in the string using Regex

Comment: some indication of the language you are using would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

For specific such as above

```
172\.60\.136\.[0-9]{1-3}
```

which nails it specifically to the range of 172.60.136.0 through 999

of course that doesnt cover valid only IPs, that would allow 172.60.136.0 or  172.60.136.999

```
(0?0?[1-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])(\\.(0?0?[0-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])){2}(\\.(0?0?[1-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4]))
```

Does test that the IP is valid, it allows 1.0.0.1, through 254.254.254.254, wont allow anything ending in .0 etc.

Comment: +1 for providing a regex as the OP requested.  Bit of a nightmare to read though

Comment: yeah its a bit of a mouthful. But to get the fact that 0's can be in th emiddle as 10.0.0.1 is very valid, but 0.x.x.x isnt nor is x.x.x.0 etc, and in the case of the above allows for people who typed 010.000.000.001, just to be annoying...

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
$tmp = explode(',', $ips);
$tmp = array_map('ip2long', $tmp);
if (array_search(false, $tmp, true) !== false) {
    // at least one ip is invalid
}
```

Comment: Didnt noticed, that its not specified in the question. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure regex is your best option here as ip addresses are only valid if the numbers are 254 or less

I would split the string at the commas and then split each one of those by a period.  I would check that there are 4 sections and that each section can be converted to a number which is 254 or less.

something like this untested pseudo code

```
string[] addresses = myString.Split(",");
foreach(string address in addresses)
{
    string[] numbers = address.Split(".");
    if (numbers.Length==4)
    {
         Foreach(string number in numbers)
         {
              // need to check that the last number is not a zero as well - not shown here
              int value = Convert.ToInt32(number);
              if (value<0 && value>254)
              {
                  //invalid
              }
         }
    }
    else
    {
        //invalid
    }
}
```

there are probably classes you could use in your language to help with this but you don't say what language it is. You could do this in c#:

```
string[] addresses = myString.Split(",");
foreach(string address in addresses)
{
    IpAddress ipAddress;
    if (!IpAddress.TryParse(address, out ipAddress))
    {
        //invalid
    }
}
```

if you just wanted to invalid ones you could do:

```
IPAddress ipAddress;
string[] addresses = myString.Split (",");
foreach (string address in addresses.Where (address => !IPAddress.TryParse (address, out ipAddress)))
    {
        //all elements in this loop will be invalid entries
        // remove the '!' to get only the valid ones 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/
```

Comment: this will only validate a single 'ipaddress' won't it? where as the example contains a string with many, comma seperated.  Also the numbers could be any invalid values

Comment: yes...correct is there any way to handle the comma seprated ipaddress